# How to plot outcomes over time with standard deviation

Tags: python

the question I have been asked is as follows:
Problem 6) Professor Derek is worried about outcomes over time for his age bracket (30-40). He wants you to plot the relative frequency of positive outcomes (y-axis) over time (x-axis) while also including 1 standard deviation above and below each point. You should not compute Spearman's correlation here. Fill in the function below.

The code I have tried is as follows:

```
# Problem 6) Complete where we have indicated below
def create_bar_plot_for_derek(covid19_data):
  # first we subset the data by the appropriate age bracket and do a bit of cleaning
  prof_age_data = covid19_data[covid19_data.age_range=="30-40"]
  prof_age_data=prof_age_data.replace(to_replace='25.02.2020 - 26.02.2020',value='25.02.2020')

  # and we convert the column to a date-time
  prof_age_data['date_confirmation']=pd.to_datetime(prof_age_data['date_confirmation'],dayfirst=True)

  outcomes_over_time =  prof_age_data[['date_confirmation','outcome_class']].groupby(['outcome_class']).agg(['mean','count','std']).reset_index() # Problem 6) fill in here

  outcomes_over_time = outcomes_over_time.dropna() # we should drop the rows with missing values
  
  x =  outcomes_over_time.age_range # Problem 6) fill in here
  y = outcomes_over_time.outcome_class['mean'] # Problem 6) fill in here
  error = outcomes_over_time.outcome_class['std'] # Problem 6) fill in here

  fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(20, 10))
  ax.errorbar(x, y, yerr=error, fmt='-o')
  plt.ylabel('Relative Frequency', fontsize=14)
  plt.xlabel('Date', fontsize=14)
  return x, y, error
x,y,error = create_bar_plot_for_derek(covid19_data)
```

where outcome_class is a previously defined function
I am receiving a value error of no results

Comment: Please include the traceback of the value error in full and properly formatted.